# reactjs: select box with FormGroup, how to route to other page when one option is selected

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

As the title said. I have a select box, and lets say i am on '/home', and when one of the option in select box is select, I want the page direct to '/home/test'. I tried `LinkContainer` from `react-router-bootstrap`. But it is not working with `option` tag.

Can anyone help me please? I am using `react-router` v4

```
 <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect">
        <ControlLabel>Please select one of the following: </ControlLabel>
        <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select">

            <option value="select"></option>
            <LinkContainer to={`${match.url}/test`} >
                <option value="select">TEST</option>
            </LinkContainer>
        </FormControl>
</FormGroup>

<Route exact path={`${match.url}/test`} component={Test}/>
```

Comment: Dont you have an onChange event on any of the parents?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you try to render a links in your select box and thats not going to work.

React-router's `<Link>` etc all create a tags with correct url's for you.
What you need to do is create a proper `<select>` with `<option>`s inside it. And on the `<select>` handle the `onChange` event and redirect your app from within the `onChange` handler. Either by just `window.location = "/your/new/page"` or if you want to route internal within you SPA get hold of the history object from react-router(more on that [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)).

http://jsbin.com/misewekida/1/edit?js,output

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  onUrlSelected(e){
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
    //Navigate using 'window.location =' here or use 
    //react routers "withRouter" to access the history and history.push("/your/local/url")
  }

  render() {
    return <select onChange={this.onUrlSelected}>
      <option value="www.google.com">Label 1</option>
      <option value="/some/internal/url/as/value">Label 2</option>
    </select>;
  }
}

React.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

1) I know this answer doesn't cover how to navigate from within an even handler in a detailed way but the api changes from version to version in react-router so go in to their documentation as i suggested and read how they do it for your version. With v4 its as suggested the withRouter HOC.

2) Another option could be to not create a select box but just a  list of links and style it yourself then the  inside would work, but if you need a select then this is the way to more forward.